# Perl: Scalar Found where Operator expected

Tags: perl, fetch, operator-keyword, www-mechanize, scraper

im currently programming a little Google-Scraper for another Project.

But i get the Error:

> Scalar found where operator expected at test.pl line 50, near ")
>   $elementct (Missing operator before $elementct?)
>
> syntax error at test.pl line 50, near ") $elementct"
>
> Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTML::Parser;
use HTML::Tree;
use warnings;

open (F, "testlist.txt") || die "Could not open test.txt: $!\n";
my @listelement = <F>;
close F;

do {
    my $elementct  = 0;
    my $donk = $listelement[$elementct];     
    my $bot = WWW::Mechanize -> new(); 
    $bot -> agent_alias ('Windows IE 6'); 
    $google = "http://www.google.com/search?q=yoursearch+";
    $search_url = "$google $donk";
    $bot -> get ($search_url);

    my $page = 1;

    do {
        my $tree = HTML::Tree -> new();

        $tree -> parse ($bot -> content);

        #Store the Links in an array
        my @link = $tree -> look_down ('_tag','cite');

        # Check if we got something, exit otherwise
        if (!@link)
        {
            print "\nERROR NO RESULTS\n\n";
            exit 1;
        }

        # Print the results per page
        print "\nResults from Page $page\n";
        for my $url (@link)
        {
            print "|__ ".$url -> as_HTML."\n";
        }
        $page++;
        # increment page numbers
        $bot -> follow_link (text => $page);
        print  "\n";
        sleep 3;

    } while ($page < 4)
    $elementct++
} while ($elementct < scalar @listelement)
```

and i dont get what i have to do to fix it after reading alot similar asked questions.

(Its my first time coding with perl, i wanted to learn it and thought it would suite the Project.)

Thanks for your time and help
WDC

Comment: Please turn on `strict` too.

Comment: `while ($page < 4)` → `while ($page < 4);`

Comment: I'm not sure if you're getting a subset of links or all of them on the page, but note that Mech has a `->links()` method that will return a list of WWW::Mechanize::Link objects to you.  You can also use `->find_all_links()` and pass criteria to it to filter the links that you want.  This is all without having to use HTML::Tree yourself.

Comment: Thanks, i will try it when my current solution works:)

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
do { ... } while ($page < 4) $elementct++;
```

and

```
($page < 4) $elementct++
```

is not a valid expression. You meant to write

```
do { ... } while ($page < 4); $elementct++;
```

Comment: Okay thank you, pretty dumb mistake, but $elementct is still not incrementing, or it is and $listelement[$elementct] is just not working.
You have an idea for that as well?

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`. This will find your error.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
    } while ($page < 4)
    $elementct++
    } while ($elementct < scalar @listelement)
```

Because there's no `;` `$elementct++` is being treated as part of the `while` condition, which isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

#### Fatal errors

- As others have noted, you  need a semicolon `;` at the end of a `do { ... } while ...` loop
- You have a scoping problem with `$elementct`, which would have been revealed if you had `use strict` in place as you should. You are trying to increment the variable outside the block that contains its declaration

#### Best practice guidelines

- It is *vital* to have both `use strict` and `use warnings` (in preference to `-w` on the shebang line) at the top of every program you write
- The `do { ... } while ...` form of loop is very rarely what you want, as it will always execute the body of the loop at least once regardless of the loop condition. Use the more standard `while (...) { ... }` unless you're certain you need something more special
- You should use *lexical* file handles instead of the global `F`, together with the three-parameter form of `open`

Your code should look something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTML::Parser;
use HTML::Tree;

my @listelement;
{
    open my $fh, '<', "testlist.txt" or die "Could not open test.txt: $!";
    @listelement = <$fh>;
    chomp @listelement;
}

my $elementct = 0;

while ( $elementct < @listelement ) {

    my $elementct  = 0;
    my $donk       = $listelement[$elementct];
    my $bot        = WWW::Mechanize->new();
    my $google     = "http://www.google.com/search?q=yoursearch+";
    my $search_url = "$google $donk";

    $bot->agent_alias( 'Windows IE 6' );
    $bot->get( $search_url );

    my $page = 1;

    while ( $page < 4 ) {

        my $tree = HTML::Tree->new;

        $tree->parse( $bot->content );

        #Store the Links in an array
        my @link = $tree->look_down( '_tag', 'cite' );

        # Check if we got something, exit otherwise
        if ( !@link ) {
            print "\nERROR NO RESULTS\n\n";
            exit 1;
        }

        # Print the results per page
        print "\nResults from Page $page\n";
        for my $url ( @link ) {
            print "|__ " . $url->as_HTML . "\n";
        }
        ++$page;

        # increment page numbers
        $bot->follow_link( text => $page );
        print "\n";
        sleep 3;

    }

    ++$elementct;
}
```